# Migrate vagrant Ubuntu VM to physical machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet, vagrant, image

I am attempting to use vagrant and a puppet workflow to configure a Ubuntu production server VM which will host a web application.  I want to be able to reuse this workflow to configure multiple identical VMs in the future.  After the VM is configured, I am attempting to create an image and migrate the VM to the physical machine.  I am planning on using a PXE Imaging service like fog to create an image of the VM then deploy on a bare metal machine.

My questions are:

Will I run into any incompatibility issues / does there exist and do I need a utility similar to sysprep?

Is there a more efficient set of tools I could be / should be using for this situation?

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to migrate a virtual machine to physical, you want to be able to reproduce a certain configuration tested in a virtual machine in a set of physical ones.

You're almost there, you can choose to control the process more or less manually:

1. PXE boot the new machines
2. configure the basics with [`preseed`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed)
3. hand the system over to [`puppet`](https://www.puppetlabs.com/) for it to finish the configuration of your system.

Or use a provisioning server like [`cobbler`](http://www.cobblerd.org/), which can handle PXE, [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cobbler/Preseed), repository management and has [`puppet` integration.](http://www.cobblerd.org/manuals/2.6.0/4/3/2_-_Puppet_Integration.html)

Comment: Okay, so as far as I understand, I will need to host a cobbler server to handle deployment of my customized configuration.  Sounds great thanks! I will read into cobbler more.